# Symfony2 Entity method called in repository class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I call method from entity class in repository class.
I had tried to do something like this, but no success.

```
class ProfileConnectionsListRepository extends EntityRepository
{
       public function connectionUserNames($userId)
       {
           $connections = $this->_em
               ->findOneBy(array('user1Id' => $userId))
               ->getUser2Id();
       }
}
```

so if this is invalid can do something like that on doctrine way without using raw queries.

Comment: Check the result of `findOneBy`. It should be your entity, but maybe also `NULL` if no user with the given ID was found.

Comment: What is result of `$this->_em->findOneBy(array('user1Id' => $userId));`?

Comment: What do you mean by no success? What does `$this->_em
               ->findOneBy(array('user1Id' => $userId))` give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to get repository first.

```
$connections = $this->_em
   ->getRepository(UserEntity::class)
   ->findOneBy(array('user1Id' => $userId))
   ->getUser2Id();
```

Comment: Thanks you mate, you save my nerves :)

Comment: Been there. Glad to help :)